# How to use transform.position on GUI.Button

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Hey i wondered if i could use a public Transform to declare where to position the GUI.Button.

For an example :

```
Public Transform buttonPosition;

void OnGUI()
{
GUI.Button(new Rect(buttonPosition.position, 100, 100), "Test");
}
```

Comment: Stop using OnGui and use the [new UI system](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/the-new-ui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OnGUI()` was used pre Unity 5 for the main GUI, but it is not deprecated as of yet and it remains as a toolset for developers to draw simple UI with for debugging purposes. You should really use the new UI that was implemented in Unity 5 if you are looking for production UI. (`UnityEngine.UI` also supports rotation, scaling and position in the transform system)
Answering your question, there is no function to rotate `GUIContent` as the type `Rect` does not include a rotation vector/quaternion. Please see the attached image for more details.
Have a good day.

[Unity GUI.Button Argument List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeUmO.png)

**Further reading:**
`OnGUI`/`GUIContent`
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html
`UnityEngine.UI.Button`
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button.html